# mouseover parent = find() child id name

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

when mouseover `#divlayer`, `find()` id of child `span`

HTML:

```
<div id="divlayer">
        <p>title</p>            

        <span id="apple">apple</span>
        <span id="orange">orange</span>
        <span id="kiwi">kiwi</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('span').hide();
$('#divlayer').mouseover(function(){
    $('span').show();
    $(this).find(???).attr('id');
});
```

edit: my bad, I should have clarified my question. the `span`children are hidden, when the mouse pointer goes over `<p>title</p>`, id of **each** `span` child is returned.

Basically, `<p>title</p>` is visible at first, and when the mouse goes over the it, children are shown and ids are returned individually.

Comment: There are three of them, which one do you want to find? The one hovered? Well if you know it's always one of them, are you not better off doing `$('#divlayer span').mouseover` so that you can access it by `$(this)`?

Comment: do you need the id of the child the mouse is over or the id's of all children?

Comment: @David Hedlund, @ITroubs, @Felix Kling....when the mouse goes over EACH span, return its id.

Comment: i updated my answer to match your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update

```
$('#divlayer').mouseover(function(){
    $('span').show();
});

$('#divlayer > p').mouseover(function() {
    $('#divlayer').find('span').each(function() {
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this.. (Edited to meet your last requirements)

```
$('#divlayer').mouseover(function(){
    $('span', $(this)).each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: span children are hidden, I dont want them to be targeted

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="divlayer">
    <span class="mouseoverClass" id="apple">apple</span>
    <span class="mouseoverClass" id="orange">orange</span>
    <span class="mouseoverClass" id="kiwi">kiwi</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#divlayer').mouseover(function(){
        var accumulator = new Array();
        $(this).find('span').each(function(a,dom){accumulator.push(dom.id);});
        alert(accumulator[0]);
    })
});
```

here you have it. it takes all id's and pushes it onto accumulator. then you can do whatever you need with these id's

Comment: this should be what you want.

Comment: actually it has to be the divlayer. the children are hidden

Comment: hidden where? behind another overlaying div?